# Spring boot maven plugin: spring-boot:start shuts down the web app immediately (using jetty)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When I use IDE or `mvn spring-boot:run` command from command line to bring up my app it works fine but when I try to use `mvn spring-boot:start` it brings up the server and then closes it immediately. 
Here is the trimmed log (Note: the closing after build success)

```
2019-04-30 23:05:32.700  INFO 23764 --- [lication.main()] com.Application         : Started Application in 30.875 seconds (JVM running for 36.058)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.027 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-30T23:05:32+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 124M/1714M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-04-30 23:05:33.203  INFO 23764 --- [      Thread-13] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4ea8f6f3: startup date [Tue Apr 30 23:05:02 UTC 2019]; root of conte
xt hierarchy
```

My pom.xml looks like has everything it needs. It also contains `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I could not find anything in their documentation that could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to spring boots guides on run and start

[spring-boot:start](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/start-mojo.html)

[spring-boot:run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html)

basically put, "start" is designed to run more as a script and terminates itself when it reaches the end of the code, where as "run" starts the program as an application which doesn't terminate when it reaches an end point in the code.

hope that helps a little.

Comment: I get that part of it but "start" is supposed to keep the web app running until "stop" is called. This way I can run my integration tests which is what the "start" is built for.

Comment: @KartheekMannepalli do you have the full output log? is it returning any errors? is it just starting, black screening then stopping?

Comment: There are no errors in the log and the most important part of the log I have added to the main post. You can see the first line where it says the server is up and the last line where it is closing the app. All this happens within fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the version of the spring boot maven plugin I was running. Once I moved to the new release version I no longer see this issue.

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: just for clarity are you using the parent POM or BOM to manage dependencies? It might explain the discrepancy as the BOM can only manage dependency versions whereas the parent POM can handle plugins too.

Comment: This fixed it for a short while and now I see the same issue again.